# This particular line of code seems to work with Rails 2.x.x but not 3.x.x? Can someone please help to "translate" it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, class, nomethoderror

```
<li<% if @flits.first == flit %> class="first" <% end %>>
```

I created css for `#flits_list` and `#flits_list :hover` in `application.css` in Rails 3 but I would like the first `flit` in the list (`flits_list.first`) to have different css so I created a class, but this code returns the error

> no method error in home#index. you have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of array. the error occurred while evaluating nil.first

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: think we may need the controller code where @flits is being created to answer this one as the error is telling you that @flits is nil

Comment: home_controller.rb says: before_filter :login_required def index @flits = current_user.all_flits end end

Comment: simple enough - so that would suggest that current_user.all_flits is returning nil ....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that @flits is nil, presumably because your all_flits method is returning nil.

However, I'd recommend not putting that logic in the view, breaking up a tag like that. You have several options to make it cleaner:

---

Option 1: Use the CSS pseudo-class `first-child` like so:

```
 li:first-child {
    ...
 }
```

This has the advantage of not requiring any back-end logic or special markup. The only downside is that it has spotty older browser support, e.g. IE6.

---

Option 2: Use the Rails tag helpers.

```
<%= content_tag :li, :class => @flits.first==flit?"first":"" %>
```

---

Option 3: Tuck it away in a helper method

```
<%= li_for_flit %>
```

Then in the helper:

```
def li_for_flit
   #spit out your tag here
end
```